# Java Application Fails At Build Time

Tags: java

I am migrating an application from Quartz 1.8 to Quartz 2.2.2. In order to build my application I added quartz-2.2.2.jar and c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar. I am building my application using jdk-1.6 version. While building my application I am getting below error:

An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.6.0_29). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com/sun/tools/javac/comp/MemberEnter$3 from class com/sun/tools/javac/comp/MemberEnter
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.importNamedStatic(MemberEnter.java:244)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.visitImport(MemberEnter.java:542)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCImport.accept(JCTree.java:495)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.memberEnter(MemberEnter.java:387)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.memberEnter(MemberEnter.java:399)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.visitTopLevel(MemberEnter.java:512)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCCompilationUnit.accept(JCTree.java:446)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.memberEnter(MemberEnter.java:387)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.complete(MemberEnter.java:819)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:386)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java:763)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:464)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:442)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:822)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:727)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:353)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:279)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:270)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.Javac13.execute(Javac13.java:56)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1065)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:882)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor33.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:416)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor33.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:416)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor33.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:416)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
```

Please help me out here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.6.0_29). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport) after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates." Upgrade to a modern JDK if possible; if not, at least upgrade to the latest Java 6 JDK, which was u45.

Comment: No enough information provided, please read the How to Ask section.

Answer (score 0):

java docs about `IllegalAccessError` :

> Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only
>   occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly
>   changed.

So you are probably accessing something from `Quartz 1.8` than isn't available in `Quartz 2.2.2`.

> An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.6.0_29)

your compiler is pretty old `Quartz 2.2.2` maybe using some new java features

Comment: Thanks Raman,

I tried with quartz-2.1 jar which I think is compatible with jdk 1.6 but even with quarz 2.1 it is giving me the same error.