# Quartz 2.2.2 compatibility with JDK

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Is Quartz 2.2.2 or Quartz 2.1.7 compatible with JDK 1.6 ? I want to know about the compatibility of Quartz 2.2.2/2.17 with JDK Version.

Please help me out here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

yes: ---Quartz now requires JDK 1.6 or newer (QTZ-286)
https://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/new-in-quartz-2_2

Comment: I am using JDK 1.6 but seams it is not compatible.

Comment: Error:An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.6.0_29). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
 java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com/sun/tools/javac/comp/MemberEnter$3 from class com/sun/tools/javac/comp/MemberEnter

Comment: Please update your answer with this information. This is possible  a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873805/java-application-fails-at-build-time

But there is no answer

Comment: I tried with Jdk 1.6.0_45 (Latest), but it is giving me the same error.